# Is there a limit to how many credentials SSMS can remember?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

Using SQL Server Management Studio that came with SQL Server 2008 R2, I make connections to the same server using a number of different sets of SQL Server Authentication credentials. On my development machine, I use the `Remember password` checkbox extensively to avoid having to look up the password each time.

When I choose a Login which I have previously connected with (using Remember password), the Password entry field gets populated with asterisks, and clicking Connect allows me in - **most of the time**. But sometimes, with no pattern that I can discern, on choosing a previously-used Login, the Password field will prepopulate with asterisks, **but clicking Connect tells me the login fails**. I enter the password, click Connect, and get in, and then typically the next time I use the same login it will work.

My suspicion is that there is a maximum number of credentials that SSMS is prepared to remember, and only the most-recently-used `n` credentials are *actually* remembered, but I can't find any mention of such behaviour in the documentation.

Is there a known limit on how many credentials SSMS will remember?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is still a bug (sql server 2008 - 2014 (version 12.0.2000.8 still affected)) as highlighted below :

[SQL Server 2012 Management Studio spuriously forgets password, despite being set to remember it.](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/779351/sql-server-2012-management-studio-spuriously-forgets-password-despite-being-set-to-remember-it)

You can vote up the connect item to get it HOPEFULLY fixed if you are experiencing the bug as well.

```
%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\SqlStudio.bin
```

might have a limit but I don't know of any kind of hard limit.

BTW, how big is your sqlstudio.bin file now ?

Comment: Thanks for the link. My SqlStudio.bin is currently just over 100 kilobytes.

Comment: @AakashM weird.. mine is 145KB, but I dont experience what you do. You are probably saving everything as remember password which I am not.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution worked for me in SSMS 2016 (13.0.15000.23)

In the Connect to Database Engine dialog, drop down the server name list
Use the arrow keys to select the server for which passwords aren't remembered

[image]
Press the `delete` key on the keyboard.

Comment: This worked for me! thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not have any control on the contents of recent connections box in SSMS.

I develop [SSMSBoost](http://www.ssmsboost.com/Features/ssms-add-in-preferred-connections) add-in for SSMS and I have solved this problem by adding a manageable list of preferred connections. You can simply save frequently used connections and easily switch between them using special combo-box on the toolbar.
Hope this helps.