# Sql Server Management Studio can't remember passwords

Tags: sql-server, ssms

When I connect to a database using ssms, I also have a checkbox labelled "Remember password". However, ssms will not remember the password. The next time I connect to the same server, I have to write it again.

What is the actual functionality of the "remember password" checkbox?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44229/is-there-a-limit-to-how-many-credentials-ssms-can-remember

Answer (score 2):

As said in the link from comment, It's a bug in SQL Server Management Studio

[SQL Server 2012 Management Studio spuriously forgets password](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/779351/sql-server-2012-management-studio-spuriously-forgets-password-despite-being-set-to-remember-it). and [SQL Server Management studio solution explorer doesn't remember SQL authentication password](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/342763/sql-server-management-studio-solution-explorer-doesnt-remember-sql-authentication-password)

[Some alternate solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320506/sql-server-2008-ssms-wont-remember-password) may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that password is only kept during the session with BIDS.

Comment: Are you using SQL Authentication?